# How can I check when my user account was created in AD?

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

As a Windows 7 user, how can I check when my account was created in AD? I don't have access to the domain controller, I am the local administrator on my machine though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the creation date with the following PowerShell CmdLet:

```ps
Get-ADUser <username> -property createTimeStamp |select name,createTimeStamp
```

Replace `<username>` with the username of your account.

Comment: This works, however `Get-ADUser` is not available in Windows 7 by default. I need to follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22817501/950290